# Does anyone know how to make nautilus as a file manager in Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: nautilus, xfce, filemanager, thunar

This might look like a duplicate of other questions, but it isn't.

I'd like to know how to set nautilus as the file manager....avoiding it to change anything else but the file management.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

yes I also prefer nautilus over thunar. use this command this will install nautilus without the junk.

`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nautilus`

Then go to settings manager, preferred applications and replace thunar with nautilus